# Why some taglibs in Grails returns a Closure?

Tags: grails

Why do some core taglibs in Grails return a closure? For example `createLink` ([see source](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/246b7264e8a638ada188ddba7a7a8812ba153399/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/web/taglib/ApplicationTagLib.groovy#L358))? What are the benefits or use cases?

Comment: This is an property of type `Closure` which get's a closure assigned right away.

Comment: Yes but in the docs examples only returns implicitly  `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer` so I don't understand why return a Closure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, what you are actually seeing is that `createLink` is defined as a `Closure`, not that it's returning a `Closure` when it's executed. The closure itself is executed and delegates the implementation which is responsible for the actual work of creating the `StreamCharBuffer`. 
Let's look at the source and see what's really going on:

```
Closure createLink = { attrs ->
  return doCreateLink(attrs instanceof  Map ? (Map) attrs : Collections.emptyMap())
}
```

As you can see above we have a variable called `createLink` of type `Closure` which delegates it's work to `doCreateLink`. Which happens to be a protected method within the containing class.

```
protected String doCreateLink(Map attrs) { 
  ... // actual implementation cut out of this example
  return useJsessionId ? res.encodeURL(generatedLink) : generatedLink
}
```

As you can see this is where the actual work is done to generate the `StreamCharBuffer` (Well, `String`, which casts nicely).

Now, why would you do this? One possible use case is, the method `doCreateLink` is much more strict than the closure `createLink` in the formal definition. By using a `Closure` instead of the method, the call to `createLink` can change slightly over time as enhancements or additions are made to it with (hopefully) little or no impact to previous uses of it.

Hopefully that helps explain a bit about what you are seeing and possibly why.